# Map fragment as part of an activity screen has problems dragging down/up

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have an activity screen with a map fragment which is only about 50% of the screen, the screen has other widgets as well, like Switches, EditTexts, etc.

When I drag the map left or right it moves smoothly as expected.
But when I drag it up or down it stutters and the whole screen tries to scroll up/down.
As if the focus was shared between the map fragment and the activity screen.

How can I request the focus to be exclusively for the map?
I tried `requestfocus();` but it did not solved the problem

Comment: May be it conflict with the scroll event of Activity. Please provide some images or code.

Comment: My best guess is a `ScrollView` or something similar to encapsulating your map fragment.

Comment: Its hard to detect that issue without source code.